# Dedicate USB hardware to LXC container

Tags: usb, lxc

Reading the LXC documentation, it seems possible to dedicate the physical network port eth2 to an LXC container with config something like:

```
lxc.network.type = phys
lxc.network.link = eth2
```

I'm interested in dedicating an USB port (or bus) to to a container, so that anything I connect to the dedicated ports are directly allotted to the container, regardless of what type of device I've connected. Is this possible?